# My errors array are empty when retrieving them and showing to the user

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an `Operation` class that has methods to deal with errors. These cases would be on the API side, not client side. The flow works like this: I have a `<class>Operation`, which extends `Operation` that performs whatsoever, and then, returns a result. `<class>Controller` instantiates `<class>Operation` and then either display the errors or the returned results

An example of its usage would be, inside of the `<class>Operation`:

```
if (res.error) {
  this.addError(HTTPResponse.STATUS_FORBIDDEN, res.error)

  return false
}
```

`addError`, inside of `Operation` class, is:

```
addError(code, message) {
  this.errors.push({code, message})
}
```

Then, in the `<class>Controller`, after checking there's an error, it retrieves the first one from the list:

```
if (!pages) {
  let error = linkedAccountOperation.getFirstError()

  throw new HttpException(error.message, error.code)
}
```

which corresponds to the `getFirstError` method from `Operation` class:

```
getFirstError() {
  return this.errors[0]
}
```

I logged out inside of these methods within `Operation` and confirmed that, after `addError()` is executed, the `errors` array is populated, but when executing `getFirstError()`, it's `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You said that your getFirstError() method is in your Operation class. But it is a static method with a static error variable ? Do you instantiate the Operation class several time ? In my opinion its just a context error :)

Comment: The Operation class is instantiated once per endpoint. The same endpoint - the controller - instantiates the class, gives any data to the Operation class, like name, surname etc, if any, and then it executes the method that's required for that endpoint, and this same method will treat the errors, always returning false if there is one, making use of those `addError` and `getFirstError`

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: hum it's pretty hard to see the whole process, but have you try to put a getter and setter for the error variable ? its alway a good methodology and maybe more convenient to test ?